# ¿Como logro que no se desborde el Div?

Tags: javascript, html

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Botones de la comida
var bon = document.getElementById('boton1');
bon.addEventListener("click", agregar1);

var bona = document.getElementById('boton2');
bona.addEventListener("click", agregar2)
```

[image: Esta es la imagen de lo que sucede]

```
  //Funciones para agregar la comida al recuadro en blanco

function agregar1() {
$('<p>Hamburguesa - 50 pesos </p>').appendTo('#preciosC');
}

function agregar2() {
$('<p>pizza - 100 pesos</p>').appendTo('#preciosC');
}


 });
```

Comment: no entiendo tu pregunta lo que quieres es que no se desborde el div?

Comment: si, exacto @soldat25

Comment: Asumo que depende del css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El contenedor tiene un alto fijado, los elementos hijos de este contenedor superan este tamaño por lo tanto se desbordan.

Este es el comportamiento por defecto, pero puedes alterarlo con la propiedad [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) de css.

por ejemplo, si quieres que este contenedor tenga funcionalidad de scroll, puedes utilizar `overflow: scroll`

otra forma, es modificar el comportamiento del contenedor, por ejemplo dándole la propiedad de alto automática y no limitada a un tamaño.

Comment: muchas gracias!!! me sirvio de mucho